# How to activate generic type warning in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I'm working with some Java code created in the previous version of JDK using the syntax:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But I wish to change them all to:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm wondering if Eclipse can give me some warnings for this problem? I take a quick look at [Java Compile Errors/Warnings Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm), but I'm not sure which option to choose.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be an option for that. Depending on the size of the project, have you considered using `awk` or `grep` to find all occurences? If it's a lot of work, you could probably write a script to change it.

Comment: This is something quick a dirty to print all occurences into the console. Uses `ack`. You can use `sed` to do a replacement, but, again, if it's a small number of occurrences, `ack` will show filenames and line numbers. `ack "new .*<.+>\\(.*\\)" `

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ChristopherSchneider. It's not a huge size of project, but I'll try your method. Could you provide it as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure thing, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eclipse neon (i'm pretty sure it applies to earlier versions) there is a setting.

In the Preferences dialog

Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warning.

In the section for "Generic Types" set the "Redundant type arguments" to something reasonable (i have it on warning)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be an option for that. Depending on the size of the project, have you considered using `awk` or `grep` to find all occurences?

This is something quick a dirty to print all occurences into the console. It uses `ack`. You can use `sed` to do a replacement, but, again, if it's a small number of occurrences, `ack` will show filenames and line numbers. `ack "=\s*new .*<.+>\\(.*\\)"`